# akka-streams with akka-cluster

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster, akka-stream

My akka-streams learn-o-thon continues. I'd like to integrate my akka-streams application with [akka-cluster and DistributedPubSubMediator](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/distributed-pub-sub.html).

Adding support for Publish is fairly straight forward, but the Subscribe part I'm having trouble with.

For reference, a subscriber is given as follows in the [Typesafe  sample](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-clustering?_ga=1.14327153.791372286.1453685602#code/src/main/scala/chat/ChatClient.scala):

```
class ChatClient(name: String) extends Actor {
  val mediator = DistributedPubSub(context.system).mediator
  mediator ! Subscribe("some topic", self)

  def receive = {
    case ChatClient.Message(from, text) =>
      ...process message...
  }
}
```

My question is, how should I integrate this actor with my flow, and how should I ensure I'm getting publish messages in the absence of stream backpressure?

I'm trying to accomplish a pubsub model where one stream may publish a message and another stream would consume it (if subscribed).

Comment: I'd like to close this one, because I'm opening a different question that is more specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to make your Actor extend ActorPublisher.  Then you can create a Source from it and integrate that into your stream.

See the docs on ActorPublisher here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.3/scala/stream-integrations.html

Comment: The part I'm not getting is that you normally create one actor per subscription. So, as I process subscription messages, the Flow itself becomes an actor factory. A stream would create one actor for each subscription it desires, and those actors would be tied to the life of the stream (unless I receive an unsubscribe request). I will re-read the documentation, maybe a light bulb will go off.

Comment: I figured out how to create the per-stream actor, still working on working with two sources. Thanks for the suggestion, i will update.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are outdated: they suggest using [`ActorPublisher`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/actor/ActorPublisher.html), which has been deprecated since version 2.5.0.

For those interested in a current approach, Colin Breck wrote an excellent series in his blog about integrating Akka Streams and Akka actors. Over the course of the series, Breck fleshes out a system that begins with Akka Streams and plain actors, then incorporates Akka Cluster and Akka Persistence. The first post in the series is [here](http://blog.colinbreck.com/integrating-akka-streams-and-akka-actors-part-i/) (the distributed stream processing piece is in [part 3](http://blog.colinbreck.com/integrating-akka-streams-and-akka-actors-part-iii/)).